# How to call function of Javascript from Servlet 2

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

I need to use a function of JavaScript call "datosGPS", this function is in a JPS, but I need call it from a Servlet call "ServletPeticiones" I need that the Servlet call the function without the user have to intervene
Is possible make it?

Comment: You can't directly call JavaScript from Servlet, but you can call your function onLoad or after AJAX for example

Comment: Do you really mean JavaScript or do you mean a JSP scriptlet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can print your Java Script code like,

`response.getOutputStream().println("[javascript code]");`

in the browser.

Servlets run on Web server whereas JS runs on Web browser. Its not possible to call JS from a Servlet.